# silverlight 5 feature request list?

Tags: sql-server, silverlight

Does anyone know the location of silverlight 5 feature request list? If there isnt one, shall we start it right here?

1. Ability to embed silverlight applications in Powerpoint presentations.
2. Sql server compact edition for silverlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions

There is a forum specifically for feature requests.

Comment: They moved everything to dotnet.uservoice.com.  I updated the link.